# comparing two arrays and return difference of arrays

Tags: php, array-difference

My old array data:

```
[Job] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [job_state_id] => 14
            [assigned_to_id] => 
            [patient_id] => 2
            [prescription] => main
            [case_type_id] => 1
            [upper_midline_id] => 1
            [upper_midline_value] => 0
            [lower_midline_id] => 1
            [lower_midline_value] => 0
            [treat_arches] => 2
            [upper_midline_type_id] => 2
            [lower_midline_type_id] => 2
            [overjet] => 2
            [overbite] => 2
            [arch_form] => 2
            [canine_relationship] => 2
            [molar_relationship] => 1
            [posterior_crossbite] => 1
            [procline] => 2
            [expand] => 2
            [distalize] => 0
            [ipr] => 0
            [close_all_spaces] => 2
            [other_instructions] => other
```

and my new array data:

```
[Job] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [job_state_id] => 14
            [assigned_to_id] => 
            [patient_id] => 2
            [prescription] => main complain
            [case_type_id] => 1
            [upper_midline_id] => 1
            [upper_midline_value] => 0
            [lower_midline_id] => 1
            [lower_midline_value] => 0
            [treat_arches] => 2
            [upper_midline_type_id] => 2
            [lower_midline_type_id] => 2
            [overjet] => 2
            [overbite] => 2
            [arch_form] => 2
            [canine_relationship] => 2
            [molar_relationship] => 1
            [posterior_crossbite] => 1
            [procline] => 2
            [expand] => 2
            [distalize] => 0
            [ipr] => 1
            [close_all_spaces] => 2
            [other_instructions] => other instrucations
```

you can see some values are change. I need to compare the $new array data against the $old data array and catch only the change made on the value.
i have use this code:

```
$difference = array_diff($oldJobData, $newJobData);
```

difference variable return `$oldJobData` **i want only difference not whole array**
i have use following code also but can't get desire result.

```
          $new2 = array();
            foreach ($newJobData as $key => $new_val) {
                if (isset($oldJobData[$key])) { // belongs to old array?
                    if ($oldJobData[$key] != $new_val) // has changed?
                        $new2[$key] = $newJobData[$key]; // catch it
                }
            }
```

Comment: please left comments why are you down vote ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an associative array and as such must use [`array_diff_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php):

```
$changes = array_diff_assoc($new, $old);
```

Comment: not working Array to string conversion error occured.

Comment: i have use your code $changes = array_diff_assoc($newJobData,$oldJobData); and $newJobData and oldJobData both are arrays

Comment: thanks it's my mistake,array_diff_assoc is work for me!